# How to sFTP with TIdFTP

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to use TIdFtp to automate deploying of my app by sending updated files to my site's FTP folder.

Currently i do this manually using Filezilla and SFTP, so the login / username are not exposed in the network.

As far as i know, using TIDFTP will send login / password with no encryption, exposing my site to risks. Is there a way to use TIdFtp with SFTP, so the data is trasfered to server encrypted ?

Thanks

Comment: Out of the box, no ([reference](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/1725-sftp-client/)). This seems [useful](https://github.com/superflexible/TGPuttyLib)

Comment: I guess you want FTPS, not SFTP (ftp over SSH)?

Comment: @whosrdaddy Yes, any method that will not send my login data exposed on the network. Does FTPS work this way ?

Comment: yes indeed, anyway FTPS should be possible with Indy, use the SSL IOHandlers for that

Comment: Only by using SSLIoHandler i'll be using FTPS instead of FTP ?

Answer (score 0):

At work, since GDPR, we've replaced *all* uses of TIdFTP with calls to winscp.com, see 
`/nointeractiveinput` here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline